# Generate a sequence number, skipping null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to generate a sequence number that skips null values (i.e. null values are NOT counted):

```
PAT_ID ENC_DATE  SEQ
------ --------  ---
1      null      null
1      05/01/15  1
2      01/01/14  1
2      null      null
2      02/11/14  2
```

Currently:

```
SELECT  PAT_ID, ENC_DATE
        ,case when enc_date is not null then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY end_date) end SEQ
```

Generates (a null value increments the SEQ value):

```
PAT_ID ENC_DATE  SEQ 
------ --------  ----
1      null      null
1      05/01/15  2   
2      01/01/14  1   
2      null      null
2      02/11/14  3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, do I miss something? You already skipped the null values and generated a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `NULL` check in your `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT  PAT_ID, ENC_DATE
        ,CASE WHEN enc_date IS NOT NULL 
                THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id,CASE WHEN Enc_Dt IS NULL THEN 1 END ORDER BY end_date) 
         END SEQ
        ,dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY enc_date) DR
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to have the null dates considered last:

```
SELECT  PAT_ID, ENC_DATE
,case when enc_date is not null 
  then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY ISNULL(enc_date, '2079-06-05T23:59:00')) end SEQ
,dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY ISNULL(enc_date, '2079-06-05T23:59:00')) DR
from t;
```

Result:

```
PAT_ID  ENC_DATE    SEQ     DR
1       2015-05-01  1       1
1       (null)      (null)  2
2       2014-01-01  1       1
2       2014-02-11  2       2
2       (null)      (null)  3
```

Comment: Is there a SQL Server constant the represents the maximum date value?  If so, would it make sense to use it in place of '2079-06-05T23:59:00'?

Comment: @Craig, that value represents the maximum allowable date that you can use with `smalldatetime` - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).  Most likely, Mark is using that to ensure that you don't get an out of range error if your `ENC_DATE` value is typed as `smalldatetime`, since `ISNULL()` inherits the data type of the first value passed to it, or following a pattern that he developed for use with that data type.

Comment: The `ENC_DATE` field is `datetime`.